# Why am i being detected as robot when i am replicating the exact request a browser is making?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, request, python-requests

This is the website "https://www.interlinecenter.com/" this website is making request to "http://cs.cruisebase.com/cs/forms/hotdeals.aspx?skin=605&nc=y" for loading html content in an "I-FRAME". I am making the exact same request using the same headers being sent by the browser but i am not getting the same content.

Here is the code i am using:

```
url='http://cs.cruisebase.com/cs/forms/hotdeals.aspx?skin=605&nc=y'

header = {
'Host': 'cs.cruisebase.com',
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0',
'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
'Referer': 'https://www.interlinecenter.com/',
'Connection': 'keep-alive',
'Cookie': 'visid_incap_312345=yt2dprI6SuGoy44xQsnF36dOwV0AAAAAQUIPAAAAAAAqm0pG5WAWOGjtyY8GOrLv; __utma=15704100.1052110012.1572947038.1574192877.1575447075.6; __utmz=15704100.1575447075.6.6.utmcsr=interlinecenter.com|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/; ASP.NET_SessionId=pzd3a0l5kso41hhbqf3jiqlg; nlbi_312345=/7dzbSeGvDjg2/oY/eQfhwAAAACv806Zf3m7TsjHAou/y177; incap_ses_1219_312345=tMxeGkIPugj4d1gaasLqECHE5l0AAAAAg1IvjaYhEfuSIYLXtc2f/w==; LastVisitedClient=605; AWSELB=85D5DF550634E967F245F317B00A8C32EB84DA2B6B927E6D5CCB7C26C3821788BFC50D95449A1BA0B0AFD152140A70F5EA06CBB8492B21E10EC083351D7EBC4C68F086862A; incap_ses_500_312345=6PJ9FxwJ3gh0vta6kVvwBthz510AAAAAvUZPdshu8GVWM2sbkoUXmg==; __utmb=15704100.2.10.1575447075; __utmc=15704100; __utmt_tt=1',
'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0'
}

response = requests.get(url, timeout=10, headers=header)

byte_data = response.content 
source_code = html.fromstring(byte_data)
print(response)
print(byte_data)
```

This is the response i am getting:

```
<Response [200]>
<html style="height:100%"><head><META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW"><meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no"><meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0"><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"></head><body style="margin:0px;height:100%"><iframe id="main-iframe" src="/_Incapsula_Resource?SWUDNSAI=9&xinfo=10-99927380-0%200NNN%20RT%281575456049298%202%29%20q%280%20-1%20-1%200%29%20r%281%20-1%29%20B12%284%2c316%2c0%29%20U2&incident_id=500000240101726326-477561257670738314&edet=12&cinfo=04000000&rpinfo=0" frameborder=0 width="100%" height="100%" marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px">Request unsuccessful. Incapsula incident ID: 500000240101726326-477561257670738314</iframe></body></html>
```

I need to extract/scrape data at "https://cs.cruisebase.com/cs/forms/hotdeals.aspx?skin=605&nc=y".

Note: i don't want to use the selenium webdriver to get the data any help will be much appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try getting the headers by loading the target URL directly?

I sent a `GET` request to https://cs.cruisebase.com/cs/forms/hotdeals.aspx?skin=605&nc=y with the following headers, and I was able to get the complete response.

```py
headers = { 
'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3',
'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate',
'Accept-Language':'en-GB,en;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,hi;q=0.7,la;q=0.6',
'Cache-Control':'no-cache',
'Connection':'keep-alive',
'Cookie':'ENTER COOKIES',
'DNT':'1',
'Host':'cs.cruisebase.com',
'Pragma':'no-cache',
'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests':'1',
'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36',
 }
```

I have left the `Cookie` field blank, you will have to enter cookies otherwise the page won't load. You can get the cookies from Chrome.

Comment: Yes i was actually replicating the headers sent by the browser, i wonder why was't that working?

Comment: Great it works, i was actually not refreshing the cookie.

Comment: This does not explain why that works. Which cookies does it expect to see. If I request the page for the first time the server cannot expect cookies to present since the server puts cookies to a client.

Comment: Start the request session save the cookie and then make request with new cookie  saved.

Comment: The server doesn't expect any cookies at the first request, but it loads JS/XHR files. If you don't want to pass cookies, you need to send requests to those JS/XHR URLs after the main request, and in the same session.